# Least value in nested list

Tags: python, list

i am thinking to write a program to find the least value in nested list, return the value in same list format

Input

```
ip = [[[5,4,7],[4,2,1],[1,9,5,4]],[[3,5],[6,5,2]],[2,5,3,7]]
```

output

```
op =[[[4], [[1]] , [[1]] ],[[3],[2]],[2]]
```

i wrote a function which can identify least value from the provided list

```
def smallest_num_in_list( list ):

    min = list[ 0 ]
    for a in list:
        if a < min:
            min = a
    return min
```

this works for normal list 
now i am trying to write some logic for nested list where i lost

i am trying to create something like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a8L5.png)
please some shed some light on me :-)

thank you

Comment: If your new problem is one level deeper, maybe another `for` loop will help you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to make another function `def smallest_num_in_nested_lists(nested):` where you get the smallest number in each of the nested lists. If this is correct, then you can do this with recursion. In other words, the function can call itself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```py
def fun(in_list):
    if set([type(x) for x in in_list]) == {list}:
        return [fun(x) for x in in_list]
    else:
        return [min(in_list)]

ip = [[[5,4,7],[4,2,1],[1,9,5,4]],[[3,5],[6,5,2]],[2,5,3,7]]

print(fun(ip))
[[[4], [1], [1]], [[3], [2]], [2]]
```

Comment: This is good, but replacing the condition with: `all(isinstance(x, list) for x in in_list)` would probably be slightly more effective.(due to short-circuiting).

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that:

```
 def inspectList(originalList) :
     ResultList=[] 
     for listItem in originalList:
          if isinstance(listItem, list) :
               MinVal=inspectList(listItem) 
               ResultList.append(MinVal)
          else:
               return min(listItem) 
      return ResultList


 ip = [[[5,4,7],[4,2,1],[1,9,5,4]],[[3,5],[6,5,2]],[2,5,3,7]]
 result =inspectList(ip)
 print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't know exactly how much levels to go each time, **recurssion** might be a natural selection here.

From here we need the step and the stop condition. I guess they are pretty obvious in that point: The step would be to go down one list level each time, while the stopping condition will be when we reach a *"leaf"* list - one that has no more nested lists.

In order to detect such list we can use error handling:

```py
def minimize(l):
    try:
        return [minimize(elem) for elem in l]
    except TypeError:
        return [min(l)]
```

This function iterates on the elements of its list argument and tries to add the recursive call to the result. When we make the recursive call on a *leaf* list, this call will fail because the elements are not iterable. This will throw us one level up to the *leaf* list and we return the least value.

This means that this function will work on any number of nesting, even a flat list:

```py
>>> minimize([[[5,4,7],[4,2,1],[1,9,5,4]],[[3,5],[6,5,2]],[2,5,3,7]])
[[[4], [1], [1]], [[3], [2]], [2]]

>>> minimize([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
[1]
```